# How do I use module inside module?

Tags: module, rebol, rebol3

I have this simple module:

```
REBOL[
    Name: 'test1
    Type: 'module
    Exports: [foo]
]

foo: does [print "foo"]
```

and this one:

```
REBOL[
    Name: 'test2
    Type: 'module
    Exports: [bar]
]

import %test1.reb

foo

bar: does [foo]
```

When I try to do `import %test2.reb`, I get `foo word is not bound to a context` error. 
After this error, I'm able to call `foo` from console, so it was imported, but somehow it's invisible to `test2` module. So what's the proper way to use module inside module?

Answer (score 2):

<del>I'm not certain if this is a bug in `IMPORT`, however</del> Using the `NEEDS` header should work:

```
Rebol [
    Name: 'test2
    Type: 'module
    Exports: [bar]
    Needs: [%test1.reb]
]

foo

bar: does [foo]
```

Comment: `IMPORT` is a mezzanine, it may be worth a glance at the source to try and find if there's somewhere in the order of things where the word 'foo in 'test2 is not being bound to the word 'foo in 'test1 that should now also be bound to the 'system/contexts/user context.

Comment: Or 'system/contexts/lib.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a word to the return of import

```
REBOL[
    Name: 'test2
    Type: 'module
    Exports: [bar]
]

t1: import %test1.reb

t1/foo

bar: does [t1/foo]
```

**EDIT:**

I tried using 'do, and it workded, but now I can't reproduce it. So maybe there's something else going on, or I did forget to close the console before retrying.

Comment: [This document](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/modules-loading.html) says, that `do` should be equivalent to `import`. So I'm confused.

Comment: See [Module-from-Module Import Behaviour](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/conversation/module-from-module-import-behaviour).